# Controlling voltage supply on usb port using android programming language for android powered smartphones

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is it possible to provide input from my Android smartphone to an embedded device through USB cable?

If it is possible then how can I communicate?

I am going to cut the USB end and i will directly insert the one end of the wire to Bread bode and another end connected to my smartphone.

how to control the power supply form the USB cable?
The inputs from my android to embedded systems are {00,01,10,11} in the form of electrical signals.

Comment: Good idea! But I don't think so we can control electronic signals. Might be you have to dig into Android NDK.

Comment: is there any other way to produce such an out put. foe example audio output

Comment: See this link if it helps! http://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/embedded-basics/4416138/Turn-a-Smart-Phone-into-a-Signal-Generator